# Work around temporary table in SQL Server 2008 view

Tags: sql-server-2008, view, temp-tables

I wrote a query in this format..

```
Select * INTO #xyz FROM ()
```

which I later want to use to create a view, as...

```
CREATE VIEW aaa
AS 
   Select * INTO #xyz FROM ()
```

but getting the following errors:

1. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INTO'.
2. Views or functions are not allowed on temporary tables

Can someone please suggest a workaround this? Is it possible to use temporary tables to create views?

Comment: What is your end goal?  What do you want to do with that temp table?

Comment: You can't. Views are single statement activities. You can use "CTE" to help keep code readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You certainly cannot use a select into in a view. And a termp table is not approraite either. Use a derived table that is the equivalent of the temp table instead. Example:

Suppose you had:

```
select t1.id, t2.field1 into #temp from table1 t1
join Table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
where t2.somefield2 = 'mytest'

select t1.id, t2.field1, t1.field1
from mytable2 t1
join #Temp t2 on t1.id = t2.id
where t2.somefield = 'test'
```

Then you could use:

```
select t1.id, t2.field1, t1.field1
from mytable2 t1
join (select t1.id, t2.field1 
        from table1 t1
        join Table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
        where t2.somefield2 = 'mytest') t2 
    on t1.id = t2.id
where t2.somefield = 'test'
```

You could also usea a CTE

Comment: Good of you to mention derived tables. SQL is very composable which is a joy.

Comment: Thanks, Am going to try this.

Answer (score 1):

Just as the error message says it is not possible to use temp tables.

You should use a permanent table or a CTE which can also be specified in a view.

A CTE could help you out depending on your situation. Describe your problem with some context if you think it suitable after researching what a CTE is. In short a CTE is a query that you can reference multiple times which in the past people used temp tables for.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx